# Coded ui in TFS Continuous Integration

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, coded-ui-tests

I am new to continuous integration. I have developed windows application and its smoke testing using coded ui. I want to create build and release process in TFS and want to execute coded ui tests bases on every time new build is created. I would like to know if there are any limitations for coded ui when it comes to continuous integration? I am not able to find any article so far which explains about behavior of coded ui in TFS continuous integration

Your guidance in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's worth noting that [Coded UI is effectively deprecated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/03/10/visual-studio-team-services-testing-tools-roadmap/); Selenium is recommended for web apps, and Appium is recommended for desktop apps.

That said, you need to use the `Deploy Test Agent` task to deploy interactive test agents to your target machines, followed by a combination of the `Windows Machine File Copy` (to deploy your tests to the test agents) and `Run Functional Tests` task to kick off your tests.

Comment: I do not think this is answer to my question. My question is "I would like to know if there are any limitations for coded ui when it comes to continuous integration? "

Comment: Then I don't understand what you mean by "limitations". What are you actually worried about?